# changing tooltip in visualstatemanager

Tags: silverlight, coding-style, tooltip, visualstatemanager

i want to be able to change the tooltip on Checked and Unchecked, i tried:

```
    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
      <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Storyboard.TargetName="btn">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
              <System:String>Button is checked</System:String>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
```

but it doesnt seem to work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Post some XAML/code so we know what you are talking about by "Button is checked"

Comment: i think the problem is with Storyboard.TargetProperty="ToolTipService.ToolTip" im not sure if ToolTip can be set in the visualstatemanager, or im not naming it correctly

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 0):

Once before I also, ran into the same problem. So, I left the VSM away. I made the ToolTip as Resource and applied it for the control. Using the internal state change properties I updated the tooltip value using a converter.

HTH.

Comment: yes but how...do you have code? Your answer is a little too simple.